# PHP urldecode doesn't work in my case

Tags: php

My PHP

```
echo '<div class="coverImg" style="background=url("'. urldecode($item) . '") no-repeat center center">'; } ?>
```

Output (DOM)

```
 <div class="coverImg" style="background=url(" https:="" serembangirl.files.wordpress.com="" 2014="" 11="" 20141005-071447.jpg?w="300&amp;h=400&quot;)" no-repeat="" center="" center"=""><a href="https://serembangirl.wordpress.com/2014/11/14/sometimes-i-forget/">
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the value of `$item`? Are you sure it's URL-encoded, so that it needs to be decoded?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure, $item is just a normal URL like abc.com/something.jpg

Comment: Don't you want `urlencode` in that case? You're going the wrong way to create a URL...

Comment: show your full php code

Comment: Can you dump the value of $item so we can see what it contains ?

Comment: @teeyo http://i.imgur.com/Fgv77r4.png

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you actually need to use `urldecode()`, as `$item` isn't percent-encoded in the first place. You should use `htmlspecialchars`, in case it contains characters that need to be encoded for use in HTML.

Also, you shouldn't put `"` inside the `url(...)`. The first quote is matching the quote at the beginning of `style="`, so it's ending the value.

```
echo '<div class="coverImg" style="background=url('. htmlspecialchars($item) . ') no-repeat center center">'; } ?>
```

Comment: It still have the same problem

Comment: It sounds like `$item` doesn't actually contain a URL like you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the URL is correct, the problem is in the `&` to add the second parameter which is represented as `&#038;` so you can use `html_entity_decode` to fix this :

```
echo '<div class="coverImg" style="background=url("'. html_entity_decode($item) . '") no-repeat center center">'; } ?>
```

or you can combine the two functions :

```
echo '<div class="coverImg" style="background=url("'. urldecode(html_entity_decode($item)) . '") no-repeat center center">'; } ?>
```